# Can I use SSIS to repeatedly transfer data between 2 oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, ssis, real-time, migrate

I work at distribution center (warehouse) in some retail business. I have a task to collect transaction data to my head office database (oracle) from our distribution center branches databases (oracle) which scattered over many regions in our country. 
I want to implement centralized system (many to one database) that collect data repeatedly and routinely from our databases branches to our head office database to consolidation and having it analyzed.

All of these databases are oracle, my seniors have tried using DBLink, and it doesn't worked well because DBLink often crashed and need to manually recover so it can be used again. Some tried to implement Oracle Golden Gate, but it's too pricey.

I'm thinking about to alternatively use SSIS, can i get my expectation above fulfilled? or do i have any other better options?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Why is the dblink not working?

Comment: I put the DBLink select statement in procedure and execute it with oracle job scheduler. The problem is when it's pulling data, whether the DBlink and Insert statement in branches side or the DBlink and insert statement in head side, it's often executed for too long and never finished unless it's terminated manually (kill session). I wish, if it's never finished, it could catch by exception and skip the process, so the process will repeated again the next day, but unfortunately it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're proposing (loading many systems into one) is often called an ODS (operational data store), which in turn can be used to populate a "Data Warehouse"

Yes you can use SSIS to do what you want. But it doesn't always play nicely with Oracle drivers. Plus you need to pay some kind of licencing. Also if your DBLink issue is due to network then SSIS is not going to solve that problem

Depending on how much data you have , you might be better off setting up a process that uses one of the various [Oracle Tools](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/impexp.htm) to export data to a file, copy the file to a central location, then upload it into your central database.

How big are your site databases? How many records in the biggest table? You need to work out if it's practical (size wise) to export the entire database

How up to date does the data need to be in your reporting database?

Also.. there's no reason you need to load all the final data into Oracle. You could find a free (or cheaper and easier) database to load it into.

If your DBLink issue is down to network instability, then a dump and copy operation is going to be a bit more reliable (and restartable) than either DBLink or SSIS

Comment: I see, the problem with the DBLink it just i don't know if i can set time out to stop stuck process, I'll try SSIS that probably might show different result, if the result still the same, maybe i'll try transfer by file or building the system manually so i can control the time-out for stuck process. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Perhaps the DBLink issue is that there is just too much data. SSIS won't solve that - it'll take just as long (in fact probably longer). Have a try anyway